# SQL search how many days in date field counting multiples of same date as only one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date field im using in my SQL database. I am trying to figure out how to search the date field to see how many days are in it. A lot of times the same date is repeated for different entries but multiple entries of the same date should still only count as one day. How do you search that?

What Iv tried saying my date field (Date_Complete) is more than one

```
<cfquery name="processedLate" datasource="dns"> 
      Select * 
      FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work 
      WHERE Date_Received between <cfqueryparam value="10/6/2015"/> 
        AND <cfqueryparam value="10/29/2015" />
        AND Date_Complete > 1 
        AND Completed_Late = 'Y';
</cfquery>
```

[image]

So I am searching the date range between when the entry was received with the WHERE `Date_Received`, then I want to find all the fields in that date range that are marked with Y as `Completed_Late` and then count how many days in the `Date_Complete` if there is a repeat day that still only counts as one day. So in the example above there are 4 Y's but two are the same day so the count should be 3. Since I am trying to figure out how to write a query for the "NUMBER OF DAYS WHERE ITEMS WERE PROCESSED LATE"

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) tag it with the database you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: One thing you need to do is put your date values in single quotes, like this   `'10/29/2015'`

Comment: what is the data type of the Date_Complete field?

Comment: Hi @Vicki,, Plz share us with some i/p and expected o/p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Select DISTINCT(DATE_Received) 
FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work 
WHERE Date_Received between 10/6/2015 
AND 10/29/2015
AND Date_Complete > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

> A lot of times the same date is repeated for different entries but
>   multiple entries of the same date should still only count as one day

from the above,

My assumption is that, You want to get the distinct date

```
Select Date_Received  ,count(*)  
          FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work 
          WHERE Date_Received between 10/6/2015 
            AND 10/29/2015
            AND Date_Complete > 1
group by Date_Received
```

use `group by` if you want aggregation